# Powershell popup with if statements

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell line that looks like the following:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $pause = $wshell.Popup("Stop and verify...", 0, "Wait!", 48+1)
if ($pause -eq 'OK')
    {
        Write-Host 'You clicked OK'
    }
if ($pause = 'Cancel')
{
Exit
}
```

When running it, both answers result in the code ending without a printout of "you clicked OK" or exiting the program. It will not continue the script past the point of selecting OK or Cancel.  I'm not sure if its the value of the buttons or the way that they are called in the if statement.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Aztec22. Can you clarify what you mean with "having trouble"? What are you getting and what do you want to get?

Comment: Yes, I have added a bit more to my question. Basically, after the user selects one of the buttons in the popup, either OK or Cancel, the script just ends without executing either command in the IF statements.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the script.

1.

```
if ($pause = 'Cancel')
```

it is invalid comparison operator. In fact, it is assignment, not comparison. Replace `=` with suitable operator, e.g. `-eq`.

2. main issue:

`$wshell.Popup` returns integral value that corresponds to pressed button. Here is a map table for return values and their codes:

```
OK     = 1
Cancel = 2
Abort  = 3
Retry  = 4
Ignore = 5
Yes    = 6
No     = 7
```

you need to check against button codes, not against their names.

Comment: Thank you so much! Must have gotten a little stuck in SQL brain. When I used the values you provided it worked just fine!

Answer (score -1):

*Maybe this can help you.*

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$pause = $wshell.Popup("Stop and verify...", 0, "Wait!", 48+1)

if ($pause -eq '1') {
    Write-Host 'You clicked OK' 
}
Elseif ($pause = '2') {
    Exit
}
```

Comment: please add some info to your Answer about WHY your version Answers the Question. [*grin*]